# How to solve Mist wallet error - The procedure entry point SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow could not be located in the dynamic link library SHELL32.dll

Tags: mist, bug

I am running windows vista on a 64-bit operating system.
I can download mist wallet for windows fine and extract it. But once I try to start ethereum wallet I get the error: The procedure entry point SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow could not be located in the dynamic link library SHELL32.dll.
Is mist not compatible with vista? If it's not what are the best ethereum wallets with smart contract functionality? Is there any way to fix this error?

Comment: On the corresponding reddit thread Alex van de Sande seems to think this is an issue / bug: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4fiuah/still_cant_run_mist_wallet_help_would_be_greatly/